How can I get my "limit rotation" bone constrains to work WITH the rest of my armature instead of against it?
I have a rig that has a few "limit rotation" constraints inside of its mouth parts (so that the jaw doesn't open too wide or clip through). I am happy with how my rig works in its neutral position.
However, even when everything's parented to the head bone, the bones don't want to adjust their constraints to match the position of the head. At least not well!
Video of the rig and the issue

It's because your constraint is in 'World Space' and not in 'Local Space'.
